# Best way to create image for different environment

Tags: spring-boot, docker, configuration, containers, docker-image

What is the best way to maintain Images for different environments and why?

Option : 1
Create diff images for the specific environment dev, stg, prod. we have to tell Jenkin job for which environment we are building the image and spring boot will load the specific configuration files.
advantages :
Environment specif images.
disadvantages :
Every environment will have diff images so we have to build it everytime.

Option : 2
Build 1 image, externalize the config file. While building the image create a shared/mount path place an appropriate config file. While initialization load the config file.
advantages:
One image can be used by all the environment.
disadvantages :
Custom Configuration handling.
Need coordination between 2 teams.

Let me know if there are other options and whats the advantages and disadvantages above approach or any other approach are present.

Comment: Option 3, specify the environment specific overrides in a K8s configuration map. Or environment variables in Docker Compose or whatever you are using. I would avoid building divergent images.

Comment: @BoristheSpider  Need coordination between 2 teams. is there any way to read the config from my resource folder and make it available at runtime?

Comment: You can use spring profiles and then set the profile for the environment or trigger it somehow else. The coordination aspect is still there - as the service team then needs to maintain configuration for every environment and coordinate with the environment owners to ensure the configuration is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Build once and deploy anywhere is considered as the fundamental principles of the continuous delivery (Google it for its advantages). So I would build the same image for all environments . And when running the image , it needs to have some ways to allow configuring these configurations based on the environment.

In term of docker , it allows to configure the environment variables when running a container (e.g see [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) in case of docker-compose)

In term of spring-boot, the OS environment variables will [override](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) the application properties in the app.

Comment: I'd add to this: IME Spring profiles aren't a good match for this setup, since it means you have to rebuild everything to update the properties built into the jar file if the operations team changes a host name.  Configure the application principally with environment variables.

Comment: Agree that the configuration should be configured principally through OS env. variable. And spring-boot does allow to configure which profiles will be enabled through the OS env. variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`

Answer (score 0):

When designing your images, split the filesystem and environment into 3 pieces.

1. Binaries, runtime, libraries, code needed to run the application. This belongs in your image.
2. Configurations and secrets that will differ for different users of the image. These belong in configuration files and environment variables that are injected at runtime (either as a bind mount, docker-compose.yml env vars, k8s config map, etc).
3. Data. This should be mounted as a volume, or in an external database accessed with a configuration/secret.

This keeps with the [12 factor](https://12factor.net/) design and enables portability, easier testing, and less risk with deploying something into production that is different from what was tested in CI.

Answer (score 0):

You can build docker image for each environments separatly.

for example: read variable of `dev environment` from `.env.dev` file.

Answer (score 0):

create images that contain specific configurations for every environment